# How to display data from a nested graphQl query

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I am trying to display data from a nested graphql query and keep receiving back 400 status code error.

What I am trying to pull back is LocGroups.name

Thanks in advance

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Query } from "react-apollo";
import gql from "graphql-tag";

const LOCATION_QUERY = gql`
  query LOCATION_QUERY {
    user {
      userEnterprises {
        userEnterpriseInfo {
          LocGroups {
            name
            locGroupId
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

class LocationsSelector extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Query query={LOCATION_QUERY}>
          {({ data, error, loading }) => {
            if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
            if (error) return <p>Error: {error.message}</p>;

            return (
              <div>
                {data.user.userEnterprises.userEnterpriseInfo.LocGroups.name}
              </div>
            );
          }}
        </Query>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LocationsSelector;
```

Comment: A 400 error normally means your query failed validation. Please check the network tab for the exact error message being returned by the server and update your question to include this message.

Comment: Here is the error I am getting from the network tab  errors: [{message: "Cannot query field "LocGroups" on type "Enterprise". Did you mean "locGroups"?",…}]
0: {message: "Cannot query field "LocGroups" on type "Enterprise". Did you mean "locGroups"?",…}